# Calling perl script from a perl script

Tags: perl, bash, shell

I want to call a perl script from a perl script with big argument list in a bash shell. The arguments contains special characters such as `\`, `*`, `(`, `)` etc. Each of these special characters are guided by single escape character `\`.

But when I call 2nd perl script (which then calls to a shell script) from 1st perl script the escape character gets evaluated and the special characters are exposed in the shell and hence getting syntax error.

So basically i want to prevent escape character's evaluation when I call 2nd perl script from 1st perl script and it should be evaluated when I call shell script from my 2nd perl script.

Eg. Input to the first perl 'MonitorAdmin' script is :

```
MonitorAdmin -reversefilter -container="LogServerContainer" -filepath="/home/esg2/YogeshTemp/VSDEFAULT/logs" -filename="System.log" -pattern=".*\t.*\t(DEBUG)\t.*\t.*\t.*\t(SecurityService)\t.*\t.*\t.*\t.*\t.*" -linecount="5001" -targetfile="
```

Comment: I want to avoid adding another escape character to the arguments given to the MonitorAdmin script.

Comment: Show us your buggy code so we can fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two forms of [`system`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html), one that executes a shell command (`system($shell_cmd)`), and one that launches a program (`system($program, @args)`). As best as we can tell by your light post, you appear to be using the wrong one. All you need is

```
system('MonitorAdmin2', @ARGV)
```

There is no shell to "misinterpret" the characters.

Comment: Yes this appears to solve the problem about the special characters but now facing another problem viz. I want to pass few more arguments to the MonitorAdmin command along with @ARGV list. How would I do that in this form of 'system' command?

Comment: @Yogesh, It doesn't have to be an array, much less `@ARGV`. Just build an expression that returns the appropriate list.

Answer (score 2):

Perl's `exec` and `system` commands won't invoke a shell if you pass them a list with more than one element, but each list element becomes a separate argument then, i.e. spaces don't separate arguments.  I'd imagine this works well even when executing a shell script since you aren't invoking the shall with a `-c` option.

Comment: There are 3 layers involved here, first call goes to MonitorAdmin perl script which executes another perl script like this: system "bash" , "-fc", "2ndPerlScript @ARGV" and then this 2nd perl script accumulate the user argument with the help of getoptions and propagates them to a shell script like this : system "bash", "-fc", "ShellScriptName $ARGUMENT_LIST"

Comment: But the problem is that when I pass on the @ARGV list in subsequent calls, the escape characters gets evaluated.